# Extended Events - "Watch live data on screen as is captured" can not be selected

Tags: azure, ssms, azure-sql-database

While I am trying to use "Entended Events", the option "Watch live data on screen as is captured" can not be selected.

[image: Screen shoot]

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test:

'Watch Live Data' is not available in SQL database yet. That's because the function [sys.fn_MSxe_read_event_stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-msxe-read-event-stream-transact-sql) is not available in SQL database, and it's being used by SSMS when using 'Watch Live Data'.

Comment: How can we trace\Profile queries? As per my understanding profiler also not supported on Azure SQL...